# Power function in php to calculate 17^2147482999

Tags: php, pow

I am trying to make a power function to calculate the power of 17^2147482999.
I tried this code:

```
function ipow($a, $b) { 
    if ($b<0) { 
        echo "B must be a positive integer";
    } 
    if ($b==0) return 1; 
    if ($a==0) return 0; 
    if ($b%2==0) { 
        return ipow($a*$a, $b/2); 
    } else if ($b%2==1) { 
        return $a*ipow($a*$a,$b/2); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

The function call:

```
echo ipow($a, $b);
```

The error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in C:\wamp\www\spoj\LASTDIG.php on line 23
```

Is there any other way to calculate the power for such big values? The inbuilt `pow()` function is giving an `INF` output.

### **UPDATE**

If it seems impossible to get the whole answer, is it possible to extract atleast the last 5-10 digits of the answer by some mathematical approach?

Comment: Why 2147482999? (I won't ask about the 17).

Comment: Wolfram Alpha calculates it, but doesn't display the whole result. Apparently it has 2,642,368,140 decimal digits.

Comment: I just gave a sample. I have values bigger than 2147482999 to work with.

Comment: The fatal error you get is from `xdebug`. If you disable it, your function could work (though it's likely to be very, very slow, and you're better off with `bcpow` as suggested by mario, and it shouldn't require to edit configuration options).

Comment: You killed my python shell... :(

Comment: You can rewrite recursive functions always into loops. But I doubt it will give any sort of meaningful result. It will reach the `INF` float as PHPs built-in function does.

Comment: @Coding-Freak - I typed `17**2147482999` on my python shell and...
:P

Comment: @JiminP - Atleast my PHP pages dont crash. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [bcpowmod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcpowmod.php) function like this:

```
<?php echo bcpowmod(17,2147482999,10000000000); ?>
```

the result is `8849802353` which means, 17^2147482999 mod 10000000000 or, the last 10 digits of 17^2147482999 is 8849802353.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that with plain PHP arithemtic operations. That's way out of range for integers, even on 64-bit systems.

You need to use the bcmath extension and the [`bcpow`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcpow.php) function. (If that doesn't work maybe even `gmp`.)

```
 print bcpow(17, 2147482999);
```

Comment: Hmm. So even if it would terminate the calculation, PHP would run out of memory with that result string. So, it's clearly a math problem, not an easy coding fix.

Answer (score 3):

The resulting value is something in the order of 1e+2642368139, a lot more than can fit in most libraries. If you want some approximation, you can use some logarithmic logic:

```
17^2147482999 = 10^(log(17^2147482999))
    = 10^(2147482999 * log(17))
    = 10^(2147482999 * 1.23045)
    = 10^(2642368139.79773)
    = 10^2642368139 * 10^0.79773
    = 6.27669e+2642368139
```

Answer (score 1):

[GNU Multiple Precision](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) and namely [gmp_pow](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-pow.php) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into [BigInteger](http://pear.php.net/package/Math_BigInteger), the constant PHP_INT_MAX will tell you how big an integer your platform can handle. On 64 bit this returns 9223372036854775807, wich is far from for your result in decimal notation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the algorithm and instead of working with numbers (as the data type) ... work with plain strings. It will take a lot of time to compute it but it will be achievable :)

Comment: won't fit in the memory of a 32bit system.