# How to calculate 2^n in integer where n is in between 10 to 10000 in php?

Tags: php, bigint, integer-arithmetic, bigdata

I am working with some logical problems in my localhost. At a case I need to calculate power of 2 and sum them in integer type to proceed next case. I am using 32 bit system, so I can calculate up to 2^31, as well as sum up to 2147483648 in integer type.

How can I increase the number of power up to 10000? Is there any math library or class available to calculate big integer effectively?

Probably I dont need the power over thousand but I am curious if it is possible in PHP or not. Can anyone answer my with proper reference ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274606/power-function-in-php-to-calculate-172147482999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two libraries available in PHP to work with **BIG Numbers**.

They are,

1. [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)
2. [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php)

In both of them **GMP** has more library function then **BC Math**.

> GMP - It considers leading zeros in a number string as meaning the
>   number is in octal, whereas 'BC' doesn't. Reference:
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php

Comment: thanks for the reply. Trying to work with BC math. Looks like it will just do fine for me. :)

Comment: Your welcome, Please accept it as correct answer if it helped you. It might also help future SO users.